# JDO API with Datanucleus, is too noise while using ANT

Tags: java, api, ant, jdo, datanucleus

I use ANT to run my JDO application example implemented using Datanucleus solution. When I run it I see a lot of INFO lines generated by Datanucleus. How can I get rid of them?
It takes a certain property set?

Problem is that after initialization operations are over, appears a notification message and then wait to receive a response from the user. The first letter keys to enter first, do not reach the application, can not be read. Only after the first ENTER key the application is running as it should. And I think this behavior is caused by these INFO lines from Datanucleus, not sure.

Example:

[java] 19.01.2011 23:02:58 org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager initialiseSchema
[INFO: Catalog "AgendaEMail", Schema "" initialised - managing 0 classes
[java] Continue ? (Y/N)
Y
Y
[java] Add: 1
[java] Edit: 1

As shown in this example I had to type the letter Y for 2 times to continue to next step, after the application was ready to start. Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataNucleus does NOT cause any such prompt.
And you only get log messages to the console if YOU configure it to do that, so configure the logging to go to a log file. All of this is in the DataNucleus docs

Comment: A reference to the documentation you are referring to would be helpful.

Comment: Just go to the DataNucleus docs for the version you're using and the link is there on that page "Logging". Navigation to it can't be simpler